# Single-entry Schengen visa on cruise that stops outside of the Schengen area

Tags: visas, schengen, tourist-visas, cruising

I am embarking on a cruise that has one overnight stop outside the Schengen area. I have applied for a multiple-entry visa but have only been granted a single-entry visa.

If I go on an excursion with the cruise ship, does this count as leaving the Schengen area?

If I do not leave the cruise ship at that port, does that count as staying within the Schengen area?

Apart from this port, I will only be staying and travelling within the Schengen area.

Answer (score 1):

I saw in cruise documentation:

> A multiple entry visa will be required if a non-Schengen country is
>   visited in between visits to Schengen countries (Example: depart from
>   Italy, visit Turkey, arrivin Spain).

What I don't know: if you can go around this requirement by not disembarking at non-Schengen port. I won't count on that, try to get an another visa from your embassy, stating the reason why the existing one won't do.

Comment: Indeed it's very unlikely that not disembarking could help, because how would the Schengen authorities know who on the boat had our had not disembarked?

Comment: @phoog If you had your passport with you, and it won't have turkish entry/exit stamps, they can be reasonably sure that you didn't. However, AFAIK cruise passengers don't use passports, instead they use cruise cards, which aren't updated for every port (are they?).

Comment: The point is, though, that after calling at a non-Schengen port, the ship will almost certainly be treated as arriving from outside the Schengen area.  New passengers could have embarked there.  The immigration officers won't go to the trouble of trying to segregate those who did disembark or join the vessel there from those who did not; they'll just treat everyone as arriving from outside the area.